# PERMANOVA: removing dominant species to avoid dispersion effect

Tags: multivariate-analysis, heteroscedasticity, ecology, dispersion, vegan

Dear StackExchange community,
I have an ecological dataset that contains several species from different sample sites. One species is extremly abundant that contributes 80 - 90 % to the entire community in each sample. Therefore, I sqrt-transformed my dataset to reduce the discriminatory power of this prevalent species. When I check the multivariate homogeneity of group dispersion to rule out statistical significant effects through a disperson effect, the outcome of the betadisper test of the "vegan" package is statistically significant. Since I am more intrested in potential changes in the composition of the less dominant species, I excluded the prevalent species from PERMANOVA analyses. My question is, is it reasonable/appropriate to exclude the most dominant species in my case? Is there any literautre that addresses this issue?
Thank you in advance for your answer and help.